# What does "off-hue" constitute in the context of analyzing a sample using the Pt-Co color scale?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, color

ASTM D1209, the method describing how to perform the Pt-Co color scale test for a sample, recommends reporting material that can't be matched to a particular standard as "off-hue". For color based analyses, how is "hue" measured/quantified and what is the distinction to "color"?

Comment: I'm not buying the standard to answer the question so this is an educated guess. I assume that you'd make standards of various concentrations which would have various hues of yellow. You can't make standards of every concentration so the sample is bound to be between standards. Yellow is thus the color, the "deepness" of the yellow color is the hue.

Comment: My disconnect is how one differentiates between the color (how to define the difference between yellow and orange - pick some wavelength?) and the "deepness". Should I be looking for distinctions in some spectrometer measurements (absorbance, reflectance, transmission, etc.) or something else all together?

Comment: Sorry, did some poking around without being able to find the standard itself. I  had the wrong interpretation of *hue.* The scale seems to be for yellows and yellows only . Thus if some sample is orange, then it is *off hue*.

Comment: I think of hue meaning the difference between something like sunflower yellow and a faded yellow-I guess I think "hue" and "shade" are synonyms and if I had a sample that was orange I'd think I have some major problem if I am expecting some shade of yellow.